# Проблема доступа к сетевой папке samba

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba

Установил и настроил Samba на Ubuntu Server 22.04 в локальной сети. Создал папку и настроил доступ любому желающему. С винды в проводнике вбиваю локальный адрес сервера, успешно на него захожу, и вижу свои созданные на нем сетевые папки, но при попытке в них зайти, виндовс внезапно не может найти сетевые имена. Мучался с этим вопросом продолжительное время, прошерстил весь гугл, не нашел ответов :(

на ufw разрешены все нужные для samba порты (пробовал полностью отключить ufw - не помогло), у сервера статический адрес 192.168.0.10, дал к папке права доступa - chmod 0775 share/

Прилагаю всю нужную информацию:

конфиг smb.conf:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = Samba Server
   netbios name = samba-server
   security = user
   map to guest = bad user
   dns proxy = no

[share]
   path = ~/share
   browsable = yes
   writable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0755
```

статус сервиса:

```
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-12-25 13:01:15 UTC; 2s ago
   Docs: man:smbd(8)
         man:samba(7)
         man:smb.conf(5)
Process: 196848 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)


Main PID: 196898 (smbd)
 Status: "smbd: ready to serve connections..."
  Tasks: 4 (limit: 4508)
 Memory: 8.7M
    CPU: 110ms
```

[image: ошибка подключения к папке]

Comment: `path = ~/share` - это чё такое?